# If-statements more consise

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

Is it possible to make this more consise by combinding `if` statements with `&&` or something else? I've tried a lot and I cant seem to make it work. If I could get any example on one or two rows of the code I would be very thankful. The order has to stay as it is.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == button[0])
        display.append("7");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[1])
        display.append("8");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[2])
        display.append("9");

    if (ae.getSource() == button[3]) {
        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[0] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if (ae.getSource() == button[4])
        display.append("4");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[5])
        display.append("5");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[6])
        display.append("6");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[7]) {

        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[1] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if (ae.getSource() == button[8])
        display.append("1");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[9])
        display.append("2");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[10])
        display.append("3");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[11]) {

        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[2] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if (ae.getSource() == button[12])
        display.append(".");
    if (ae.getSource() == button[13]) {

        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[3] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if (ae.getSource() == button[14])
        clear();
    if (ae.getSource() == button[15])
        getSqrt();
    if (ae.getSource() == button[16])
        getPosNeg();
    if (ae.getSource() == button[17])
        getResult();
    if (ae.getSource() == button[18])
        display.append("0");
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the order in which the buttons are put into the buttton array?

Comment: Might be able to change to a `switch` statement but it wouldn't really be any more concise.

Comment: don't these number Buttons have the Number to be inserted as text? for these do `display.append(button.getText())` (obviously the button must be 'extracted' from the event first)... more OO would be to have a different ActionListener for each button, no `if` or `switch`  needed

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jaco0646 It needs some work before it may be acceptable though. For example, all context is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere outside the function, possibly as a `final` member, I would define a hash table.

```
final Map<JButton, String> translation = new HashMap<>();
translation.put(button[0],  "7");
translation.put(button[1],  "8");
translation.put(button[2],  "9");
translation.put(button[4],  "4");
translation.put(button[5],  "5");
translation.put(button[6],  "6");
translation.put(button[8],  "1");
translation.put(button[9],  "2");
translation.put(button[10], "3");
translation.put(button[12], ".");
translation.put(button[18], "0");
final Map<JButton, Integer> functions = new HashMap<>();
functions.put(button[3],  0);
functions.put(button[7],  1);
functions.put(button[11], 2);
functions.put(button[13], 3);
final Map<JButton, Runnable> runnables = new HashMap<>();
runnables.put(button[14], () -> { clear(); });
runnables.put(button[15], () -> { getSqrt(); });
runnables.put(button[16], () -> { getPosNeg(); });
runnables.put(button[17], () -> { getResult(); });
```

I would then use it as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(translation.keySet().contains(ae.getSource())
    {
        display.append(translation.get(ae.getSource());
        return;
    }

    if(functions.keySet().contains(ae.getSource())
    {
        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[functions.get(ae.getSource())] = true;
        display.setText("");
        return;
    }

    if(runnables.keySet().contains(ae.getSource())
    {
        runnables.get(ae.getSource()).run();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you beat me to it: I'd create a `Map<JButton,Runnable>` which will also be able to contain the non-number buttons.

Comment: I would use an Enum with all button values and it should have a variable that will hold text for each button.

Comment: @daniu Good idea.  Let me whip that up

Comment: Is my lambda syntax ok?

Comment: BTW, this lends itself very well to writing a JUnit test to verify that only one of the `Map`s contains each button.

Comment: You can create Runnables for the `display.append`s and function execution as well, so you just need one map.

Comment: That would be more concise, but I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguishing what is to be done in one single event listener by looking what the source is, is a sufficiently outdated technique.

Better would be to use Action, and provide one for every button (constructor or `setAction`).

A less disruptive alternative would be to use `setActionCommand` for every button:

```
// On initialisation:
button[0].setActionCommand("K7");
button[1].setActionCommand("K8");
button[2].setActionCommand("K9");
button[3].setActionCommand("F0");
button[4].setActionCommand("K4");
button[5].setActionCommand("K5");
button[6].setActionCommand("K6");
button[7].setActionCommand("F1");
button[8].setActionCommand("K1");
button[9].setActionCommand("K2");
button[10].setActionCommand("K3");
button[11].setActionCommand("F2");
button[12].setActionCommand("K.");
button[13].setActionCommand("F3");
button[14].setActionCommand("Mclear");
button[15].setActionCommand("Msqrt");
button[16].setActionCommand("Mposneg");
button[17].setActionCommand("Mresult");
button[18].setActionCommand("K0");

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    string category = ae.getActionCommand().substring(0, 1); // K/F/M
    String parameter = ae.getActionCommand().substring(1);

    if (category.equals("K")) { // Key
        display.append(parameter);
    } else if category.equals("F")) { // Function
        int f = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[f] = true;
        display.setText("");
    } else if category.equals("M")) { // Math Operation
        if (parameter.equals("clear")) {
            clear();
        } else if (parameter.equals("sqrt")) {
            getSqrt();
        } else if (parameter.equals("posneg")) {
            getPosNeg();
        } else if (parameter.equals("result")) {
            getResult();
        }
    }
}
```

This decouples JButton from the event listener. Hence a keyboard listener for the key 7 could trigger an action event "K7" with a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Assumes it will aways be found
    int index = IntStream.range(0, 19).filter(i -> ae.getSource() == button[i]).findFirst().orElse(0);
    if(index < 3) {
        display.append(Integer.toString(index + 7));
    }
    if(index == 3) {
        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[0] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if(index > 3 && index < 7) {
        display.append(Integer.toString(index));
    }
    if(index == 7) {
        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[1] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if(index > 7 && index < 11) {
        display.append(Integer.toString(index-7));
    }
    if(index == 11) {
        temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        function[2] = true;
        display.setText("");
    }
    if(index == 12) {
        display.append(".");
    }
....
```

This makes it slightly shorter but if you cannot remap the buttons like Mark said then you're stuck with roughly the same structure since the program always will reflect the logic of your application one way or another.

Edit.
You may also make a switch after converting to an int (since switches requires constant conditions)

```
    int index = IntStream.range(0, 19).filter(i -> ae.getSource() == button[i]).findFirst().orElse(0);
    switch(index) {
        case 0:
            display.append("7");
            break;
        case 1:
            display.append("8");
            break;
            ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To collapse a pair of statements into an expression joined by logical condition, and hence, have a single body, the pair of statements must have the same (or at least similar) body. It doesn't appear to be your case.

One thing you can try is to impose a particular ordering of the array of button and design a mapping function to perform a desired action based on the index on which the button is located. But this approach is not robust at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can write all the `display.append(...)` in a `for loop` something like this

for the 0 to 2 range

```
IntStream.range(0,3).forEach(x -> {
  if (ae.getSource() == button[x])
    display.append(Integer.toString(x + 7));
 });
```